# LISP functions that perform both symbolic and numeric operations on expressions using +, -, *, and /

Tags: lisp, numeric, clisp, operations

I'm currently working on a LISP exercise for a small project and need severe help. This may be more or less of a beginner's question but I'm absolutely lost on writing a certain function that takes in two unevaluated functions and spits out the result dependent on if the variables were given an assignment or not.

An example would be

```
(setq p1 '(+ x (* x (- y (/ z 2)))))
```

Where

```
(evalexp p1 '( (x 2) (z 8) ))
    returns (+ 2 (* 2 (- y 4)))
```

My goal is to write the evalexp function but I can't even think of where to start.

So far I have

```
(defun evalexp (e b) )
```

.. not very much. If anyone could please help or lead me in a good direction I'd be more than appreciative.

Comment: what 'two unevaluated functions'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full solution. It's pretty straightforward, so I'll leave out a full explanation. Ask me in the comments if there's anything you can't figure out yourself.

(Using `eval` to do the actual evaluation might not be what you want in your exercise/project. Look up "meta-circular interpreter" for another way.)

```
(defun apply-env (exp env)
  (reduce (lambda (exp bdg) (subst (cadr bdg) (car bdg) exp))
          env :initial-value exp))

(defun try-eval (exp)
  (if (atom exp)
      exp
      (let ((exp (mapcar #'try-eval exp)))
        (if (every #'numberp (cdr exp))
            (eval exp)
            exp))))

(defun evalexp (exp env)
  (try-eval (apply-env exp env)))
```

Comment: This is amazing and works perfectly. LISP can be such an elegant language but if you don't understand it, it can certainly be a real pain in a butt. I've been trying to hack away at it but I don't think I'll get anything as simple and neat as you have it. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint, this is how you might do it (in pseudocode):

```
function replace(vars, list):
    for each element of list:
        if it's an atom:
            if there's an association in vars:
                replace atom with value in vars
            else:
                leave atom alone
        else:
            recursively apply replace to the sublist
```

There will certainly be some details to work out as you convert this to Lisp code.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the immediate reply. I'm going to try and work on that now. Very much appreciated!